# PHP form MySql EDIT / UPDATE - Can't get form to populate with data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm very new to PHP and MySQL. I've created a form which creates rows in my MySQL tables, I created a page that shows all those entries. Now I'm trying to edit those entries. I created another form that should populate with info from the selected row..the only problem is that it's not. Here's all my code including login.php...just in case. Please let me . I've looked everywhere for an answer and couldn't find one. All I found was mysql and not mysqli.

```
<?php //login.php
$db_hostname = 'localhost';
$db_database = 'mydata';
$db_username = 'user';
$db_password = '123#';

// Connect to server.
$link = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
if (!$link) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysqli_error());
}

// Select the database. 
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($link, $db_database);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use database : ' . mysqli_error());
}
?>
```

> edit_client.php

```
<?php
$title = "Edit Client Form";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $title ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<div> <!-- form container div -->
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div> <!-- form description div -->
            <h2><?php echo $title ?></h2>
            <p>Edit a client here.</p>
        </div>

<?php
require_once = 'login.php';
// get value of id that sent from address bar
$id=$_GET['id'];
if(isset($id)) {
$sql="SELECT * FROM `clients` WHERE client_id='$id'";
$result=mysqli_query($sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['client_id']; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $row['first_name']; ?>" required><br />
        <input type="text"name="last_name" value="<?php echo $row['last_name']; ?>" required><br />
        <input type="text"name="company_name" value="<?php echo $row['company_name']; ?>" ><br />
        <input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo $row['address']; ?>"><br />
        <input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $row['city']; ?>" required><br />
        <input type="text" name="state" value="<?php echo $row['state']; ?>" required><br />
        <input type="number" name="zip_code" value="<?php echo $row['zip_code']; ?>" required><br />
        <input type="tel" name="tel_number" value="<?php echo $row['tel_number']; ?>"  required><br />
        <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $row['email']; ?>" required><br />
        <input value="Submit" type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here's the table from "display_client" that sends the ID to the edit_form.php page

```
<td align="left">' . '<a href="\edit_client.php?id=' . $row['client_id'] . '/">Edit</td>
```

any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated. thank you.

As suggested below I have used PDO Prepared statements to achieve my desired result. Thank you thank you! @nomistic !

```
<?php
$title = "Edit Client Form";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $title ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<div> <!-- form container div -->
    <form action="update_client_submit.php" method="post">
        <div> <!-- form description div -->
            <h2><?php echo $title ?></h2>
            <p>Edit a client here.</p>
        </div>
            <?php
            require_once 'login.php';

            if(!empty($_GET['id'])){
                $client_id = intval($_GET['id']);
            }

            try {
            $results = $db -> prepare('SELECT * FROM clients WHERE client_id = ?');
            $results -> bindParam(1, $client_id);
            $results -> execute();

            } catch(Exception $e) {
                echo $e -> getMessage();
                die();
            }
            $row = $results -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            ?>  
        <input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="<?php echo $row['client_id']; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $row['first_name']; ?>" required><br />
        <input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?php echo $row['last_name']; ?>" required><br /> 
        <input type="text" name="company_name"  value="<?php echo $row['company_name']; ?>" required><br />
        <input type="text" name="address"  value="<?php echo $row['address']; ?>" required><br />  
        <input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $row['city'] ?>"  ><br />
        <input type="text" name="state" value="<?php echo $row['state'] ?>" required><br />
        <input type="text" name="zip_code" value="<?php echo $row['zip_code']; ?>" required><br /> 
        <input type="text" name="tel_number"  value="<?php echo $row['tel_number']; ?>" required><br />
        <input type="text" name="email"  value="<?php echo $row['email']; ?>" required><br />
        <input type="submit" name="sumbit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to do something with the post data, right now you aren't doing anything. You'll need an sql statement `UPDATE clients SET field = value WHERE id = :id`

Comment: It's not clear where your problem is.  Is it that you aren't updating the data (there's no update query?)  or is it that you can't get the data into your form?   Oh, there's some odd syntax  in your link to the form, but it may be because you copied only part of it?   It should be `<td align="left"><a href="'edit_client.php?id=' . $row['client_id'] . '">Edit</td>` etc

Comment: thanks. sorry I wasn't clear enough. I haven't created my post data file yet because I still can't get the update form to populate with the information from the database row.

Comment: Understood.  see answer below.  It should solve this problem.

Comment: take a look at some modifications and some suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit, reducing this and correcting a potential problem in you query.*

you need a loop to get the data.  It should be have something like this (using your data)

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
if(isset($id)) {
$sql="SELECT * FROM clients WHERE client_id=$id";
$result=mysqli_query($sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);


    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {


 echo  '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row['client_id']. '">';

    }
```

**Note:**  You may want to look into using prepared statements;  they are pretty easy to learn, especially at this stage, and you will have a lot of advantages, such as not having to worry about whether you are quoting int and varchar variables in your query;  you'd declare them separately.  They are also MUCH more secure (preventing SQL injection) and can make large queries run faster.    You would just need to switch to object oriented style.  (note, listing your variables in your select is what you should be doing anyway rather than `select from *`).  The select is shortened a little for ease of explanation.

Here's an example of how yours would work with mysqli:

This is your database connection (not much different, just slightly different syntax)

```
$db_selected = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database)

if  ($db_selected->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $dbc->connect_error);
}
```

Here are your queries.  `bind_param` just identifies the item as an `INT` and then replaces the `?` in the query with the variable $id, and `bind_result` takes the results of your query and turns them into variables.

The rest is fairly self-explanatory

```
$sql = $db_selected->prepare("SELECT client_id, first_name, last_name FROM clients WHERE client_id= ? ");
$sql->bind_param("i", $id);
$sql->execute();
$sql->store_result();
$sql->bind_result($client_id, $first_name,$last_name);

while ($sql->fetch()) {
 echo  '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$client_id. '">';   
 echo  '<input type="text" name="first_name" value="'.$first_name. '" required><br />';
 echo  '<input type="text" name="last_name" value="'. $last_name. '" required><br />';  
}

$sql->free_result();
$sql->close();
```

If you need some more information, here are some resources:  **[mysqli prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)**

Comment: that is, starting after the line that ends `$result=mysqli_query($sql);`   Don't call the `$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);` before the while loop or it will skip the first row, and you won't get any results.

Comment: I'm still stuck. I will dive into it all night. I was able to get it working with mysql but I shouldn't be using that anymore right?

Comment: I'm sure something here is wrong., `<?php
require_once = 'login.php';
// get value of id that sent from address bar
$id=$_GET['id'];
if(isset($id)) {
$sql="SELECT * FROM 'clients' WHERE client_id='$id'";
$result=mysqli_query($sql);
}while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

 ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['client_id']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $row['first_name']; ?>" required><br />
    //rest of my data
<?php
} 
?> `

Comment: yes, don't use `mysql_` connections.  I'll take a look at it again.

Comment: Okay I cleaned it up to make it simpler, and changed it so you didn't duck out of php as much.  I noticed a potential problem in your query itself, which may have been the problem.  I'm gathering that id is stored as an integer, so I changed your query to remove the quotes around it.   This should work.

Comment: I also added some syntax and explanation for how to use a much better way using mysqli prepared statements.   Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! PDO Prepared statements worked like a charm!...after days of learning about them!! I have updated the rest of my code to use prepared statements (where I insert data, select and update) Thanks again!